# complex filter sequelize js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following entities:

```
Product            [id, name]  
Properties         [id, name, product_id]  
Values             [id, name, property_id]  
Offer              [id, product_id]
OfferDetail        [offer_id, property_id, value_id]
```

I want to do the following filter in sequelize:

```
product_id
[property_1, value_1], [property_2, value_2], ...
```

which will return all products having the corresponding values.

Example:

```
Products
[{1, Potato}, {2, Tomato}]

Properties
[{1, Color, 1}, {2, Size, 1}, {3, Size, 2}]

Values
[{1, White, 1}, {2, Red, 1}, {3, Small, 2}, {4, Big, 2}, {5, Medium, 2}, {6, Small, 3}, {7, Big, 3}]

Offer
[{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}]   (I have 3 offers, 2 for potato and 1 for tomato)

OfferDetail
[{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {3, 3, 6}]  
meaning:
Potato: {Color White}, {Size Small}
Potato: {Color Red}
Tomato: {Size Small}

I want to be able to filter:
Potato Small
Potato (White or Red)

or a mix of them.
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand the result, can you explain it further or show an example?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of complex query, you can try using raw query

```
select p.name, group_concat(distinct pr.name separator ',') as prNames, group_concat(distinct v.name separator ',') as prValues from OfferDetail od join Offer o on o.id=od.offer_id left join Properties pr on pr.id=od.property_id left join Values v on v.id=od.value_id left join Products p on p.id=o.product_id group by od.offer_id
```

Could you check this query?

Comment: I don't think I get it. Can you please give me what it looks like if I want to filter for 3 and (1 or 2) values, meaning Small and (White or Red)? Thanks

Comment: Could you create sqlfiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data?
I will explain you further